# Language and Targets missing in Publishing Service 2.0

Tags: publishing, publishing-service, publishing-targets

I've just installed Publishing Service 2.0 and after installing (and reinstalling) the module, whenever, I try to publish, it doesn't seem to pass along the languages and targets resulting in an error.

The error the publishing service logs is this:

```
2017-02-15 09:12:37.339 -05:00 [Debug] Raising publish job started event in Sitecore event queue for job d475e63c-0b8e-411e-aa36-ebe8e56c47f6.
2017-02-15 09:12:37.356 -05:00 [Information] Job Result: d475e63c-0b8e-411e-aa36-ebe8e56c47f6 - "Failed" - "No target connections were specified.". Duration: 00:00:00.0339960
2017-02-15 09:12:37.374 -05:00 [Debug] Raising publish job end event in Sitecore event queue for job d475e63c-0b8e-411e-aa36-ebe8e56c47f6.
```

This is what the modals look like when trying to publish:

[image: This all looks good]

[image: This where it starts to get weird. There should be a language and target where the yellow is.]

So where the yellow is is where the language and target should be but it doesn't seem to be passing it along. Has anyone else encountered something like this?

Comment: Sitecore also has a patch for empty languages that will default to English. We had the same issue and they provided it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgraded from 1.1, try Clearing your browser cache, we rewrote all SPEAK dialog in 2.0. Looks like SPEAK isn't databinding to our new JSON changes.

Comment: this is rather a comment than answer

Comment: That was the fix though :-). This was discussed on slack and fixed. Just reporting the fix for anyone else that experiences.

Comment: confirmed - this was the answer.

Comment: We're definitely in the grey here. This site is not about just providing an answer for OP, it's an answer for the ages and the search engines.

Comment: @sobek85 sorry about that then.